# Deploying a Node three.js site on a server, not sure how to do it

Tags: javascript, python, server, three.js

I currently have a folder with an HTML file, a three.js javascript file and some other files. The application is run by typing in the terminal "npm i" and then "npm run dev". When I try to upload the files to the public_html folder on the server, it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

I have tried deploying on multiple platforms, as well as started learning some python for a backend framework.

Comment: `public_html` should contain the static files. The server probably already contains a web server. You should build the project on your computer and upload. Don't use `npm run dev`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

install serve or express.js

assuming your build command generates dist folder in case if. the name is different you can change this

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

to whatever built folder name is generated

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'yourBuiltFolder')));
```

create server.js and paste this code

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

don't forget to include start command in your pacakge.json

```
"scripts" : {
   "start": "node server.js" 
}
```

Comment: Why would you add another web server. Obviously, there already is a web server with a "public_html" folder.